# How can I implement a ComboBox with DataBinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I would like to translate the following from Windows Forms to WPF:

```
achievements = DB.FillDataTable(String.Format("SELECT [id], [category], [name], [description], [count_threshold1], [count_threshold2], [count_threshold3], [count_threshold4], [count_threshold5], [date_threshold], [type], [iconImage] FROM [avatar_achievement] WHERE active = 'Y' ORDER BY [name]"));
                DataRow row = achievements.NewRow();
                row["name"] = String.Empty;
                achievements.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
                comboBoxAchName.DataSource = achievements;
                comboBoxAchName.DisplayMember = "name";
                comboBoxAchName.ValueMember = "id";
```

Very simple, this takes some selections from a SQL DB and puts them into a comboBox displaying the 'name' column and storing the 'id' column as the value.  Now when the user makes a selection in the drop down, they are picking "Oranges" but my code can grab the value "222".  I need BOTH pieces of information.

How would I rewrite that exact code block so it will work in a WPF comboBox?

Comment: What have you tried in WPF so far?  You're much more likely to get help if you show the work you've already attempted.

Comment: I'd suggest reading the most basic tutorial on WPF data binding you can find (and there are plenty). Basically it's preferred to have strong-typed objects as items in an ItemsControl (which a ComboBox is) if you want to use MVVM, and it would enable you to have many interesting scenarios going forward.

Comment: its even more easier in wpf :) just google it

Comment: I googled this for over an hour and found many obscure references and nothing directly related.  Perhaps someone could provide a link to one or much such guides?  I would even mark that as an answer if the guide actually held the answer!  I am a Game Design student with only 1 year on the job experience in programming and self-teach almost everything I know so any true guidance I can get here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was tired and frustrated from a different issue when I posted this question... I could've sworn I searched all over Google yesterday... Anyway, this link gave me the answer:

[wpf combobox binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056196/wpf-combobox-binding)