# WPF ComboBox binding issue with objects

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have read several samples like:

- [wpf combobox binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056196/wpf-combobox-binding)
- [WPF: How to bind object to ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071664/wpf-how-to-bind-object-to-combobox)

But it is friday and my eyes seem square. I can't see my mistake:

```
public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; private set; }

public MainWindow()
{            
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
    this.Customers.Add(new Customer() { ID = 123, Name = "John Doe" });
    this.Customers.Add(new Customer() { ID = 456, Name = "Doe John" });
}
```

and my XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbCustomer" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Customer}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          SelectedValuePath="ID">
</ComboBox>
```

I have read that you can either use a datatemplate or the code from above. I prefer a simple dropdown, just like in webforms: `<asp:dropdownlist etc>` only then in WPF

current output:

[image: very white]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't set `DataContext` anywhere

```
InitializeComponent();
this.Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
this.DataContext = this;
this.Customers.Add(new Customer() { ID = 123, Name = "John Doe" });
this.Customers.Add(new Customer() { ID = 456, Name = "Doe John" });
```

and `ItemsSource` for should be `Customers`, not `Customer`. Same as the name of property, not the type of item

```xml
<ComboBox ... ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
```